# help date format in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
     Dim Con As OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim Sql As String = Nothing
    Dim Reader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
    Dim ComboRow As Integer = -1
    Dim Columns As Integer = 0
    Dim Category As String = Nothing
    Dim oDatumMin As Date
    Dim column As String
    column = Replace(TxtDateMax.Text, "'", "''")
    'oDatumMin = Convert.ToDateTime(TxtDateMin.Text)

    oDatumMin = DtpMin.Value
    Dim oPath As String
    oPath = Application.StartupPath

    ' Select records.
    Con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & oPath & "\trb.accdb;")
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    'Dim data_reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    Sql = ("SELECT * FROM " & cmbvalue & " WHERE Datum>='" & oDatumMin & "'")
    cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(Sql, Con)
    Con.Open()
    Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    Do While Reader.Read()
        Dim new_item As New ListViewItem(Reader.Item("Datum").ToString)
        new_item.SubItems.Add(Reader.Item("Steleks i krpe za cišcenje-toal papir-ubrusi-domestos").ToString)
        new_item.SubItems.Add(Reader.Item("TEKUCINA ZA CIŠCENJE PLOCICA").ToString)
        new_item.SubItems.Add(Reader.Item("KESE ZA SMECE").ToString)
        new_item.SubItems.Add(Reader.Item("OSTALO-džoger-spužva za laminat").ToString)
        new_item.SubItems.Add(Reader.Item("PAPIR").ToString)
        LvIzvjestaj.Items.Add(new_item)

    Loop

    ' Close the connection.strong text
    Con.Close()``
```

when i select table,(cmbvalue) from combobox 
and when i select date from datetime picker (dtp) or in last case from texbox converted to date and time sql looks like this "SELECT * FROM Uprava WHERE Datum>='2.6.2010 10:28:14'"
and all query looks ok but am geting

Data type mismatch in criteria expression. error for date (oDatumMin) when excute 
column in access is also set to date 
i have no idea what else to try

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is a localisation issue. Try changing the date format to one which should be universally recognised:

```
SELECT * FROM Uprava WHERE Datum >='2010/06/02 10:28:14'
```

[What is your server locale/code page?]

Comment: Yes, or to be even safer, use `YYYY-MM-DD` for the date, then it can't be mistaken for the wrong format even if you'd mistakenly written the year as 2 digits only, and you're compliant with ISO 8601.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Datum >= ?"
Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql)
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Datum", OleDb.OleDbType.Date))
cmd.Parameters("Datum").Value = oDatumMin
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bbw6zyha.aspx